# SQL: Syntax error or access violation

Tags: php, mysql, exception, pdo

Before I start, I looked at many other posts but none have actually helped.

I get an "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation" error. This error is being cause by this line:

```
$sql2 = $database->query("SELECT * FROM `users` LIMIT $limit");
```

$limit is:

```
$limit = ($page_id-1)*$itemsPerPage.','.$itemsPerPage;
```

My full error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-10,10' at line 1' in C:\xampp\htdocs\pdo\index.php:76 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\pdo\index.php(76): PDO->query('SELECT * FROM `...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\pdo\index.php on line 76

I've spent so long trying to work out this problem. I've tried executing the query without $limit. But that does not work.

Heres how I'm doing the for loop:

```
$limit = ($page_id-1)*$itemsPerPage.','.$itemsPerPage;
$sql2 = $database->query("SELECT * FROM `users` LIMIT $limit");

while($row = $sql2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
    //My stuff in here
}
```

If theres any sort of way someone could help, that'd be great. Thanks!

Comment: Your offset cannot be a negative number.

Comment: `-10,10` says it all: You cannot set an negative offset on your limit.

Comment: Table name should not have quotes around it. Try just 
    $sql2 = $database->query("SELECT * FROM users LIMIT $limit");
and see if it likes that better.

Comment: I don't understand that though. It worked perfectly when I used mysql_*.

Comment: Your `$page_id` var is defined and with a default integer value?

Comment: @kittykittybangbang His syntax is fine. His calculation of the LIMIT offset is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your calculation of the `LIMIT` parameters is flaky.

In this line:

```
$limit = ($page_id-1)*$itemsPerPage.','.$itemsPerPage;
```

if `$page_id` is undefined or zero your first term goes negative and results in a limit clause of `LIMIT -10,10` which is what causes the syntax error.

Make sure that `$page_id` has the value you think it has.

Comment: Heres the full code: http://pastebin.com/8BkEHeNK It's from a tutorial I've seen a while back. Everything worked fine with mysql_*, but when switching to PDO, I've had these errors. I'm also using a couple self made functions for getting values.

Comment: @Matt That's an XY question. You asked about a syntax error in SQL, but you actually want help debugging some PHP code that you haven't posted. Accept this answer if you think it's correct and create a new question with your PHP code posted in the question

Comment: I haven't asked a second question. I posted that code just in case it was any help in finding a mistake I may have made.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize `$page_id` with 1, I think the first time it's not defined:

```
if (!isset($page_id)) $page_id = 1;
$limit = ($page_id-1)*$itemsPerPage.','.$itemsPerPage;
$sql2 = $database->query("SELECT * FROM `users` LIMIT $limit");
```